# How to check filesize in IE 5 without activeX object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, activexobject

```
<script>
function GetFileSize() {
    var fi = document.getElementById('file'); // GET THE FILE INPUT.

    // VALIDATE OR CHECK IF ANY FILE IS SELECTED.
    if (fi.files.length > 0) {
        // RUN A LOOP TO CHECK EACH SELECTED FILE.
        for (var i = 0; i <= fi.files.length - 1; i++) {

            var fsize = fi.files.item(i).size;      // THE SIZE OF THE FILE.
            document.getElementById('fp').innerHTML =
                document.getElementById('fp').innerHTML + '<br /> ' +
                    '<b>' + Math.round((fsize / 1024)) + '</b> KB';
        }
    }
}
```

Getting exception "Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference" in fi.files.length

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

IE 5 predates any native browser features for interacting with local files.

Note also that IE 5 hasn't been supported on Windows since Windows NT which hasn't had a security update in 18 years.

**Do not use IE 5**